# Change a flat table to a PivotTable/crosstab that shows TEXT results instead of calculations

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a large file of survey-type information that I would like to change the format of: from a flat table to a crosstab. PivotTables don't appear to be what I want for this purpose because each response is unique text, so I couldn't assign a numeric value to the responses and then convert that using a formula once in the PivotTable.

This is the format that I have versus the format that I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1UH4.jpg

Comment: There are a set number of responses, not all of the responses answer each question, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of 3 formulas to pivot the table. Assuming that the first key (eg Case) is in column A, the second key (eg. Question) in column B and the results (eg. Response) in column C and there are say 100 rows of data.

Column header formula (in cell F1): =IFERROR(OFFSET($B$1, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E1:E1, $B$2:$B$101), 0), 0), "")

Row header formula (in cell E2): =IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(E$1:E1, $A$2:$A$101), 0), 0),"")

Cell data formula (in cell F2): =IFERROR(OFFSET($C$1, MATCH($E2&F$1, $A$2:$A$101 & $B$2:$B$101, 0), 0), "")

Copy the Column headers across row 1, the Row headers down column E and the cell data formulas to fill the table.

The Row and Column headers use a formula to extract just the unique values from the table. The Cell Data formula performs a dual key lookup to populate the results.

Sorry I don't have enough points to post images yet, you'll have to imagine the result...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing:

1. Created a new tab, pasted my case numbers in column A and removed duplicates
2. Removed duplicates from my questions and transposed them into row 1 of my new sheet
3. Created a new column in my source sheet and entered a formula to concatenate the case number and the question text
4. Started a formula in the new table to concatenate my row and column name for that cell, use VLOOKUP (because I do poorly with Index and Match) to find the right case number + question text combination that I had created in my source sheet, and return the question response.

This is the basic VLOOKUP formula that I used: 
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($A2,B$1),'Leads with Q&A'!$J:$K,2,0)

Leads with Q&A is my source sheet. Column J contains the concatenation, column K contained the question responses.

To clean up the errors from cases that did not have a question response and cases that did not ask one the questions, I used this:
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($A2,B$1),'Leads with Q&A'!$J:$K,2,0)=0,"",VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($A2,B$1),'Leads with Q&A'!$J:$K,2,0)),"")